# How to list supplementary figures in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I created several supplementary figures in my thesis using the `newfloat` package as below:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure}]{suppfigure}
```

When I create the main list of figures (`\listoffigures`) the supplementary figures do not appear in the list, only the main figures. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Is the numbering for the supplementary figures independent from the one for the "regular" figures? If so, how are the supplementary figures supposed to be listed? After the regular figures, for example?

Comment: Yes, the numbering is independent of the "regular" or main figures. However, in the list of figures I would like the supplementary figures for one chapter to appear right after the main figures of that chapter. Something looking like this:

Comment: Fig 1.1, Fig 1.2, Fig 1.S1, Fig, 1.S2, Fig 2.1, Fig. 2.2, Fig. 2.3, Fig. 2.S1, Fig. 2.S2, etc

Answer (score 7):

You can use `fileext=lof` as an option for `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` so the supplementary figures will use the same auxiliary file than the regular figures; this will produce the inclusion in the LoF, but this might be confusing since both counters are independent:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure},fileext=lof]{suppfigure}

\begin{document} 
\listoffigures
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test figure one}
\end{figure}

\begin{suppfigure}
\caption{Test supplementary figure one}
\end{suppfigure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test figure two}
\end{figure}

\begin{suppfigure}
\caption{Test supplementary figure two}
\end{suppfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better option would be to use `\listofsuppfigures` to produce a separate name; the name for this list can be changed using `listname=`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Supplementary Figure},fileext=lsf,listname={List of Supplementary Figures}]{suppfigure}

\begin{document} 
\listoffigures
\listofsuppfigures
\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test figure one}
\end{figure}

\begin{suppfigure}
\caption{Test supplementary figure one}
\end{suppfigure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test figure two}
\end{figure}

\begin{suppfigure}
\caption{Test supplementary figure two}
\end{suppfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these great suggestions. Is there a way to merge both the main and supplementary figures into one list?